# .NET 7 Identity JwtBearer - Authorize Attribute doesn't affect API

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity

I have a .NET 7 Web API which utilizes Identity and I'm trying to add JWTs. I would like to return a JWT when a user logs in and I have followed multiple examples but cannot seem to get the `[Authorize]` attribute to respond with 401 without a token, such as with my most recent attempt utilizing the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6sMPvucWNRE

The method for creating custom Jwt tokens (though I'm not sure why he made this and also uses jwt bearer).

`AuthController.cs`

```
private async Task<string> CreateToken(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            IList<string> roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value!));
            
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                    signingCredentials: creds
                );

            token.Payload["roles"] = roles;
            token.Payload["userId"] = user.Id;

            var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            return jwt;
        }
```

The controller which I want to block.

`TopicController.cs`

```
namespace SdeResearch.Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class TopicController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly SdeResearchDbContext _db;

        public TopicController(SdeResearchDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/topic/get-all-topics")]
        public async Task<List<Topic>> GetTopicsAsync()
        {
            return await _db.Topics.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using SdeResearch.Api.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CORSPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
    });
});
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<SdeResearchDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SdeResearchDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Password Settings.
    options.Password.RequireDigit= true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase= true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric= true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase= true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength= 8;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase= true;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;

    // User settings
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+!";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail= true;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseCors("CORSPolicy");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "Topic",
    pattern: "topic/*{action}"
    );

app.Run();
```

`appsettings.json`

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "Token": "Development JWT Token"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

`appsettings.development.json`

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Authentication": {
    "Schemes": {
      "Bearer": {
        "ValidAudiences": [
          "http://localhost:46355",
          "https://localhost:44326",
          "https://localhost:7174",
          "http://localhost:5132"
        ],
        "ValidIssuer": "dotnet-user-jwts"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any assistance or pointers to noob friendly documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean `[Authrize]` attribute will not response 401 error? From your code, You use asp.net core identity and jwt token together, You can try to add `builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
    {
        x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;...` and use `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

Comment: @XinranShen Correct, it wouldn't respond with a 401, I'll adjust that in the post.

This worked great, thank you so much! Next step is to also implement roles and figure out how to pass roles via the jwt. Thank you again!