# .NET 7 Controller Authorization with Identity and JWT

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt, authorization, asp.net-identity

This is a follow up to this post:

[.NET 7 Identity JwtBearer - Authorize Attribute doesn't affect API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75691048/net-7-identity-jwtbearer-authorize-attribute-doesnt-affect-api?noredirect=1#comment133535754_75691048)

I have a .NET web api communicating with React.ts and am attempting to add role based authorization via JWTs. Adding a default scheme in `Program.cs` and then adding `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` as mentioned in the comments of the above post worked great until it came time for roles. I can bypass Identity by adding tokens with roles via the cli or in appsettings, and if that's required I'll do that but I get the feeling that there is a way to pass Identity Roles in JWTs and read them from the backend.

At this time, `[Authorize(Role = "User")]` is responding with a 200 rather than a 401. Any suggestions or pointers to noob friendly documentation would be greatly appreciated.

`AccountController` token generation (commented out sections were replaced by claims):

```
    private async Task<string> CreateToken(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        //IList<string> roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User")
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value!));
            
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                signingCredentials: creds
            );

        //token.Payload["roles"] = roles;
        //token.Payload["userId"] = user.Id;

        var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        return jwt;  
}
```

`TopicController` to be blocked without role

```
namespace SdeResearch.Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "User")]
    public class TopicController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly SdeResearchDbContext _db;

        public TopicController(SdeResearchDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/topic/get-all-topics")]
        public async Task<List<Topic>> GetTopicsAsync()
        {
            return await _db.Topics.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CORSPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
    });
});
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    });

    options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value!)),
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddDbContext<SdeResearchDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SdeResearchDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Password Settings.
    options.Password.RequireDigit= true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase= true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric= true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase= true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength= 8;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase= true;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;

    // User settings
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+!";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail= true;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseCors("CORSPolicy");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "Topic",
    pattern: "topic/*{action}"
    );

app.Run();
```

`DbContext`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace SdeResearch.Api.Models
{
    public class SdeResearchDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Researcher> Researchers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ResearcherArticle> ResearcherArticles { get; set; }

        public SdeResearchDbContext(DbContextOptions<SdeResearchDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=MINE;Database=SdeResearch;Trusted_Connection=true;TrustServerCertificate=true");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData
            (
                new IdentityRole 
                {
                    Id = "DevelopmentAdministratorId",
                    Name = "Admin",
                    NormalizedName = "ADMIN".ToUpper()
                },
                new IdentityRole
                {
                    Id= "DevelopmentUserId",
                    Name= "User",
                    NormalizedName = "USER".ToUpper(),
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

***EDIT:***

After adding the following policy, and changing the authorize attribute to `[Authorize(Policy = "edittopic")]` it appears that authorize isn't doing anything. Am I missing a step with setting this up?

`Program.cs` below AddAuthentication

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("edittopic", policy =>
        policy.RequireRole("User")
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems with your code is that you lack UseAuthentication before Authoriztation. This means that the user is never created (you are always anonymous). Ie, AddJwtBearer will never be used.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

I would also add

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
```

Comment: I had both of those previously but will add them and try again, thank you. As I understand it, they're not required in .NET 7 if AddAuthentication and AddAuthorization are used, which both have been implemented at one point. I'll try again today and get back to you, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I think that even if they are not needed, I still think its more clearer if they are present, then its more obvious what is included.  Less magic is often better :-)

Comment: Makes sense! I'll leave them in! 

I tried adding `app.UseAuthentication();` and this had no effect. `app.UseAuthorization();` is already present. I also tried adding `builder.Services.AddAuthorization();` and nothing. So even with all present, `[Authorize(Roles = "User")]` has no effect and still allows access to the routes in that controlller.

Comment: I would also add app.UseRouting(); at the beginning of your pipeline.

Comment: I feel so dumb, it turns out that my browser was likely caching the user resulting in access to the API... So despite closing the server and opening it I've been able to get the results. Once I cleared my browser cache I got a 405 response.

Not sure if `UseRouting();` helped or not, but it's working so I will leave it in lol.

Now I am able to login and access the api; however, Swagger's UI doesn't require me to add the JWT in the authorize section. I assume the JWT is being automatically cached perhaps?

Comment: Great! Glad it worked! You should always have UseRouting at the beginning of the request pipeline. Feel free to accept my answer if it helped you somewhat.

Comment: I unfortunately do not see an option to accept the answer, otherwise I would. It only offers 'Share', 'Edit', and 'Follow'.

Comment: That's odd? Not a green checkbox next to the up/down arrows on the left side of the answer?

Comment: I found it; however, this didn't actually resolve the problem. A cookie is being stored which is allowing access, the jwt isn't doing anything still.

Comment: The problem is that the API (with JwtBearer) should never set any cookie, so if you see a cookie in the response, you are probably calling the wrong API/Service from the client application. Or perhaps be a bit more specific in the question?

Comment: Identity is automatically storing a cookie when the user logs in. That gives me an idea, rather than log the user in via _userManager I can check if the credentials are correct instead. I'll try this later today. Thank you for all of your help by the way.

Comment: are you not supposed to add app.UseRouting(); as well? without that the routing to the API might not work.